# Marker locations accumilate when adding a marker on a previously created Layer in Leaflet using MarkerClusterGroup

Tags: javascript, overlay, leaflet, markers

I want to add a layer on top of google maps which contains an indoor map. 
And then add the incoming events which contains latitudes and longitudes as markers on the layer which contains the indoor map.

As for now i managed to add a layer on top of the google map

```
var imageBounds = new L.LatLngBounds([p, q], [r, s]);
var imageUrl = 'assets/img/indoor.svg';
indoorMap = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {opacity: 0.7});

layerGroupIndoor = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
var overlay = {'beacons': layerGroupIndoor};
layerGroupIndoor.addLayer(indoorMap);
layerGroupIndoorControl = L.control.layers(null, overlay).addTo(map);
```

Then I added the markers dynamically to the *layerGroupIndoor* as follows.

```
layerGroupIndoor.addLayer(markerObject);
```

But when the marker locations are nearby (eg: 2 markers are nearby) the leaflet gives a new averaged location as shown below.

[image]

Any suggestion for to visualize the markers as it is?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I refer the read me [1] and made the following change and got it to un-cluster at a certain zoom level

```
layerGroupIndoor = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({ disableClusteringAtZoom: 16 });
```

1. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster